# These is a qiniu storage plugin with backup gem?

Tags: ruby, backup

I want to using [Qiniu](http://www.qiniu.com/) as storage with [backup](http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/) gem. These is a Qiniu storage plugin with backup gem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @scottysmalls Qiniu is a cloud storage service in China. And I want to backup our archives to Qiqiu through backup gem. But I can't find any solutions.

Comment: Qiniu is not an internationally known service. A better place to ask is probably a Chinese developer's forum